Connection between certain finite groups and Frobenius algebras
This question is maybe not so precise yet, but contains some ideas that maybe just search for the right definition.
Let $G=F/U$ be a finite group with presentation $F/U$ (here the presentation really matters).
I noted that when the presentation of $G$ is "nice enough", then one can associate to $G$ a finite dimensional algebra over a field $K$ (lets take $K= \mathbb{C}$ for simplicity) and we obtain a Frobenius algebra $A$ whose $K$-vector space basis is in canonical bijection to the elements of $G$ using the presentation.
I think nice enough could mean (but feel free to suggest a better definition) we do the following: Assume we have relations of the form $w_i=1$ and $w_t=w_s$. Then to get a corresponding algebra, we replaced those relations by $w_i=0$ if $w_i$ is just a power of a single element and we replace $w_i=1$ by $w_i=0$ but replace the multiplication by a plus when $w_i$ is "mixed". We replace $w_t=w_s$ by $w_t-w_s=0$ as relations in the non-commutative polynomial ring.
From $G=\langle a_i \mid w_l=1, w_s=w_t \rangle$ we then obtain the $K$-algebra $K \langle x_i \rangle /(w_l=0, w_s-w_t)$, where the number of variables $x_i$ is equal to the number of generators $a_i$.
Say $G$ has a admissible Frobenius presentation when the corresponding algebra is Frobenius with a canonical basis corresponding to the group elements in a nice way (So in particular the $K$-dimension is equal to the number of elements of $G$).
Here three examples:
a) Finite subgroups of $SO(3)$. They are classified by Dynkin types.
-Dynkin type $A_n$ has presentation $\langle a \mid a^n \rangle$ and this leads to the Frobenius algebras $K[x]/(x^n)$.
-Dynkin type $D_n$ has presentation $\langle a,b \mid a^2,b^2,(ab)^{n-2} \rangle$
and this leads to the Frobenius algebras: $K \langle x,y \rangle / (x^2,y^2,(x+y)^{n-2})$
-Dynkin types $E_n$ for $n=6,7,8$ with presentations $\langle a,b \mid a^2,b^3,(ab)^{n-3} \rangle$ and this leads to the Frobenius algebras $K \langle x,y \rangle / (x^2,y^3,(x+y)^{n-3})$
b) Finite coxeter groups given by their braid relations. Here the group presentation is given by $a_i^2$ and the braid relations stating something like $X=Y$ and we get the corresponding Frobenius algebra by simply having the relations $x_i^2=0$ and $X-Y=0$.
In this way, we get for the finite Coxter groups the nilCoxeter algebras, see for example What is known about finite dimensional modules over the nilCoxeter algebra? .
c) Any finite abelian group works, using the presentations $\langle a_i \mid a_i^{n_i}, a_i a_j=a_j a_i $ as they are product of finite cyclic groups. The resulting commutative Frobenius algebras are $K[x_1,...,x_n]/(x_i^{n_i})$.
My question is:

When does a finite group have an admisslbe Frobenius presentation? What means "nice enough" presentation, is there a better definition than what I suggested?

Since we want to get a Frobenius algebra, somehow the presentation should give us a unique longest element as for Coxeter groups.

For the nonmixed examples you seem to have the same normal forms for the groups and monoids in your examples and a unique longest element and this makes things work. I guess something like this probably works in the non mixed case if the presentation for the group is a complete rewriting system with the reduction rules always replacing the power by 1.
